# realpath on Cygwin is not same as PWD

Tags: cygwin, realpath

```
$ pwd
/home/Thomas/Utveckling/Cgreen/thoni56/cgreen
$ realpath .
/cygdrive/c/Users/Thomas/Utveckling/Cgreen/thoni56/cgreen
$ cygpath -a .
/cygdrive/c/Users/Thomas/Utveckling/Cgreen/thoni56/cgreen/
```

Why is this? Why is absolute path from the root `/cygdrive` and not `/`?

How do I get an absolute path that starts with `/home` from a relative path, such as `..`, if I'm in that tree?

Comment: have you a link in the chain ?

Comment: yes, it turned out that I did. too long ago... Could you write an answer that I can acccept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the effect of the presence of a link in the path.
Eg:

```
ls -ld /pub /tmp
lrwxrwxrwx  1 marco Administrators 19 Jun 26  2014 /pub -> /cygdrive/e/cyg_pub
drwxrwxrwx+ 1 marco Administrators  0 May  2 17:49 /tmp

$ realpath /pub /tmp
/cygdrive/e/cyg_pub
/tmp
```